# Are Verticle Integration Groups actually supported in Vert.x 4?

Tags: classloader, vert.x, java-11, isolation

I've noted that the documentation for vertx4 still shows support for Verticle Isolation Groups.

The example in the documentation refers to methods that are Deprecated for java versions less than 11, and they have been altogether removed in the java11 code.

Is there a plan for supporting class isolation in vertx4 w/ Java 11?

Answer (score 1):

There are explicitly no plans to plan to support class isolation in Vert.x 4 with Java 11. See [Issue 3274 - Isolated loading restricted to Java 8](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/3274):

> Vert.x has provided isolated class loading support in Vert.x 3 . **This
>   option cannot be properly supported above Java 8 due to the evolution
>   of the Java runtime.** In Vert.x 4 we continue provides a best effort
>   support of this option for Java 8.
>
> This relies on Multi-Release Jar support supporting this support for
>   Java version < 11 exclusively. The DeploymentOptions class for Java >=
>   11 will not provide anymore the class loading related fields and the
>   class loader manager implementation is a no-op implementation.

And while it looks like you should be OK with the feature on Vert.x 4 under JDK 8, the phrase "*best effort support*" may be cause for concern.

Vert.x 4 documentation that doesn't make it clear that isolated class loading will not be supported on any JDK > 8 should probably be updated.